# SonarQube CRLF detection using checkstyle rules

Tags: sonarqube, whitespace, checkstyle, linefeed

After migrating `maven-checkstyle-plugin` to SonarQube, I face some oddity how line feeds and tab chars are transfered.

Back in my Maven build I had the following substantial rules:

```
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, xml"/>
  <!-- forbid dos/windows lf -->
  <module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="\r\n" />
    <property name="message" value="Do not use Windows line endings."/>
  </module>
  <!-- forbid tab character -->
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true" />
  </module>
</module>
```

While checking the SonarQube report I don't see these violations, where they should be. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: SonarQube got this snippet as configured QG/QP.

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect (missing `/>` in some places). That part of the problem?

Comment: @ThomasJensen Sorry, edited the pasted text to remove some internal comments and left the file errorous. Thanks for hinting this.

Answer (score -1):

Your analysis is now based on the rules that are active in your SonarQube Quality Profile. You should re-create your rules in SonarQube.

Comment: Hi G, sorry for not mentioning, that I already added all the stuff above and added the configured Quality Gate / Profile to the upload.

Comment: To what upload?

Comment: Upload = Stuff uploaded via `mvn sonar:sonar`